# Is it possible to transfer an approved instagram client ownership from one account to another?

Tags: instagram

I don't think so (didn't find any way to do it and there is nothing in their FAQ).

The only way I see to do that is to create a new client in the other developer account and get it approved with the same information used to get the original client approved and then update the client ID / secret where needed.

Just checking if anyone knows of a better solution ?